# Is a thread to handle each client the best solution to this project?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I'm currently developing a "online" board game in C with AF_INET sockets.
It consists of a server, which is the "referee" of the game, and a client per player.
The only job of the client is to send the position of the board place selected by the player (a play) to the server, and only the server has to process each player's play. The server always broadcasts the board's changes to every player.

The main thing I'm strugling with is communication. I have 2 options:

- Implement stream sockets and in the server create a thread (and a socket) to handle each client.
- Implement only a datagram socket in the server and create a thread to handle each recieved play, identifying the player by its IP.

With the second option I have to have some data structure to hold each player's data (probably a hash table to promote fast access ),like its score, and in every recieved play 
I need to update the corresponding player's data. Whilest in the first option local thread stack variables could hold these informations.

Also, in the first option, I would have to have (with no necessity) many threads, even if recvfrom is a function with passive waiting, the kernel would have to waste time to manage all the messages and redirect them to the correct socket right?

In sum, I want to implement the most efficient strategy of client-server communication, even if it takes me more time to implement.
What's the most efficient option?

Comment: You don't need a thread per connection. Just use `poll()`, `select()`, etc. or an event loop library that manages the polling for you.

Comment: Using threads can be the right choice when each thread has a lot of complex work to do or is inclined to block (say on file or database writes) . However Shawn above is correct - you can use select() to do an awful lot if you organise your code properly.

Comment: Processing each play is rather simple, but I don't understand why I need select() (for what I understood, it tells the server who sent a message) when I already have recvfrom() which gives me the address of the sender. Are you saying that I have to create a socket in the server for each connection, and then use select() to see which file descriptor (socket) has recieved data?